Qt fails to implement object copying by dragging in a QTable with the QFileSystemModel model
The project is a file manager. It is used to display the table and Qfilesystemmodel. I can not implement copying inside the table. I wrote
tableFileSystemModel->setReadOnly(false) t

o provide access to changes in objects (files/folders). I can not copy a file by dragging an object with the ability to overwrite an existing file in the folder. In general, I would like to somehow redefine the function responsible for dragAndDrop, but I do not know how.
I enabled the drag mode - DragDrop, dragEnabled - True, the default drag action is CopyAction. Used functions
void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent * event)
{
qDebug() << "Drag center";
}

void MainWindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent event *)
{
qDebug() << "Drag";
}
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent event *)
{
qDebug() << "Drop";
}

(Written like this for debugging information)
But these functions do not work in QTable. They are triggered if an object is dragged out of QTable.

Event handlers are called on the object that receives them. If you want to get d&d events in the table, you must override those functions in the table. The only alternative is through an event filter, but it's normally discouraged for this purpose (which expects an "action" based on 3 different event types), as it usually things become messier than just subclassing.
